Open part that contains a certain value in Solidworks using vba
I wrote a script that automatically saves multiple parts within a Solidworks assembly using a Userform and VBA.
In my userform, I have multiple checkboxes that the user can click that will be saved. This works now if I use the exact name (.Caption) of the parts. That means the parts in the assembly must always be named the same.
But what if these differ slightly in each new assembly? Certain values ALWAYS occur in the parts, but sometimes the names are different.
I used random names for my form to show you:

Currently, I use this piece of code to generate an array with the selected .Captions of the checkboxes:
'Check which checkboxes are selected ans save in the array called ArrayParts
Dim Control As Control, ArrayParts As String
For Each Control In Me.Controls                                     '"Me" refers to the current userform. Can also be replaced by "UserParam"
If TypeName(Control) = "CheckBox" Then
    If Control.Value Then 'This is on a different line to prevent errors, VB checks all conditions of an If even if first one is false.
        ArrayParts = IIf(ArrayParts <> "", ArrayParts & ",", "") & Control.Caption
    End If
End If
Next
Debug.Print "CONTROLS = ", ArrayParts

My question is: is it possible to save parts with captions that can slightly differ?
For example, in case of "14mm_dentist plate S2". This part is sometimes called "14mm dentist plate S2" or "12 mm dentistplate S2". The value can be different, including spaces and underscores. However, this part always contains "dentist" AND "plate" AND "S2".
I am not sure if this is even possible and how to script this. I could not find it anywhere online.
If anything is unclear and information is lacking, please let me know and thank you in advance!

To see if a string contains certain text, use InStr.
